# Sharepoint Provider Hosted App: File Upload large file issue

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I've problems by using fileupload with files greater than 30MB.
I upload them via Sharepoint Executor (REST).

By uploading files that are greater than 30MB I get a errormessage in the console of the Internet Explorer that says that theres not enough memory...

How can I prevent this message?
Changes in the web.config doesn't appear, so I think it is a client problem.
Can I configure something in Sharepoint? Because it is provider hosted I don't know whats exactly the problem...

Here a part of my code:

```
var getFile = getFileBuffer(nextFileID);
        getFile.done(function (arrayBuffer) {

            // Add the file to the SharePoint folder.
            var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
            var fileCollectionEndpoint = calculateEndpoint(nextFileID);


            var fileData = '';
            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
            for (var i = 0; i < byteArray.byteLength; i++) {
                fileData += String.fromCharCode(byteArray[i]);
            }


            // Send the request.
            var x = executor.executeAsync({
                url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
                method: "POST",
                body: fileData,
                timeout: 3000000,
                binaryStringRequestBody: true,
                headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
                success: function (data) {
                    var file = JSON.parse(data.body).d;...
```

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,

AJ

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to SharePoint Central administration ? if so check **maximum upload size** for the web application :
Central Admin> Application Management> Manage Web Applications> Select the desired web app and click General Settings on the ribbon.

Check this [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sammykailini/archive/2013/11/06/how-to-increase-the-maximum-upload-size-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx).

Comment: This option exists only on Sharepoint OnPremise. In SP Online there's no central administration...